# How to store and read my logical operation on python

Tags: python, parsing, tokenize, logical-operators

I am making a program to filter my data using some parameters and logical operation.

I have a lot of classrooms data that has its characteristics, so each classroom will have a different filter.

```
    if classrooms == 1:
       if data[A] > data[B] & data[C] != data [D]:
         print("matched")
    elif classrooms == 2:
       if data[A] < data[B] & data[C] == data [D]:
         print("matched")
    elif classrooms == 3:
       if data[B] < data[D] & data[A] == data [C]:
         print("matched")
...
...
    elif classrooms == 5000:
       if data[R] < data[A] & data[W] == data [H]:
         print("matched")
```

since the operator is similar, is there any method to read my logical filter from my stored file to the python program?

```
"(A<B)&(C!=D)"
"(A>B)&(C==D)"
..
..
"(R<A)&(W==H)"
```

So, I don't have to write all my logical filters for each classroom in python that causing a huge line in python. I just read from my stored text data, and my python program will  interpret

```
"(A<B)&(C!=D)"
```

to this program

```
if data[A] > data[B] & data[C] != data [D]:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse the filters in your file using a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), and then construct a chain of functions from the operator module to execute the filter.

This expression

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r"""^                         # Beginning of string
                    \(                        # Opening outer parenthesis
                    (?P<operand0>[A-Z])       # First operand
                    (?P<operator0>[^A-Z]+)    # First operator
                    (?P<operand1>[A-Z])       # Second operand
                    \)                        # Closing outer parenthesis
                    (?P<operator1>[^A-Z]+)    # Second operator
                    \(                        # Opening oute parenthesis
                    (?P<operand2>[A-Z])       # Third operand
                    (?P<operator2>[^A-Z]+)    # Third operator
                    (?P<operand3>[A-Z])       # Fourth operand
                    \)                        # Closing outer parenthesis
                    $                         # End of string
                    """,
                re.VERBOSE)
```

matches the structure of your filters.

They can be matched like this:

```
m = rx.match("(A<B)&(C!=D)")
```

Parts of the filter may be accessed using the names assigned inside the `(?P<name>)` sub-expressions

```
m['operand0']
'A'
m['operator0']
'<'
```

Using a dictionary to map operators to functions from the [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module

```
import operator
lookup = {
    '<': operator.lt,
    '&': operator.and_,
    '!=': operator.ne,
}
```

you can build an expression and evaluate it

```
op0 = lookup[m['operator0']]
op1 = lookup[m['operator1']]
op2 = lookup[m['operator2']]

result = op1(op0(a, b), op2(c, d))
```

How you derive `a, b, c, d` from the operands is something you will need to work out.

The regular expression above assumes operands are single uppercase characters and operators are one or more non-uppercase characters.  This can made more precise, for example you could use the regex alternation operator `|` to make an expression that matches only the operators that are used

```
r'&|<|>|!=|=='
```

instead of the overly-general

```
r'[^A-Z]+'
```